# How can i prefield values in a multiselect box in FoundrySlate

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

I am generating values in runtime so after every reload the values in the multiselect box is getting blanked. I am taking the values from a function. so I want to prefield that multiselect value. How can we do that?

Comment: What does prefield mean? Do you mean pre-set static values?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify the `values` and `displayValues` (note: **they must both be set**) to the values that you'd like. For example, if you have a query, `q_dropdown_fields`, you should be able to set `values` & `displayValues` to `q_dropdown_fields.values` and `q_dropdown_fields.displayValues`, respectively; obviously the column names will depend on your query

Answer (score 0):

There is a concrete example with pictures in the documentation, under https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/slate/concepts-variables/ . I'm not going to copy the whole tutorial here, but this image (taken from the tutorial) should answer how to pre-set static values in a slate widget.

[image]